# Cannot use .html() while scrolling down condition

Tags: jquery, html, scroll

I have HTML like this:

```
<a href="#" class="thome">home</a>
<div class="Header"><img src="image.jpg"/></div>
```

I used this script to replace "home" text with image while scrolling down condition:

```
$(window).bind('scroll', function() {

    if ($(window).scrollTop() > 100) {
    $(".thome").html($(".Header img"));
    }
});
```

But it replaced once only. When I continue scrolling, it disappears.

Here you can see it :

http://fiddle.jshell.net/uetgrdxm/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is because this apparently removes the image from it's original parent but on each scroll that follows it will still insert that same object - but the image isn't there anymore so it's inserting emptiness instead. Adding a flag to check if the initial insertion has taken place it probably the best approach :

```js
$(function() {

var inserted = false;

$(window).scroll(function() {

 if ($(this).scrollTop() > 100 && !inserted) {
 $('.thome').html($('.Header img'));
 inserted = true;
 }
});
});
```

```css
body {
  height: 1500px;
}

a, div {
  position: fixed;
}

div {
  top: 50px;
}
```

```html
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<a href="#" class="thome">home</a>
<div class="Header">
  <img src="//www.anony.ws/i/2015/10/26/kitten.jpg">
</div>
```

Never saw it before like this. It seems to behave the same as `append()` when used in this way.

---

Update - officially you can't pass an object to `.html()` but [this blog](http://jamesallardice.com/passing-an-element-or-object-to-the-jquery-html-method/) explains it all :

> So, if you don’t pass in a string, or if an exception is thrown during the "value is a string" branch, the .html() method falls back to using .append().

The jQuery source code :

```
if ( typeof value === "string" /* ... */ ) {
    //We end up here if we pass in a string
    //...
    try {
    //...
    // If using innerHTML throws an exception, use the fallback method
    } catch(e) {}
}
if ( elem ) {
    this.empty().append( value ); //In our case we end up here
}
```

---

By request a bit more code to toggle on the given position :

```js
$(function() {

var home = $('.thome'),
headerimage = $('.Header img'),
inserted = false;

$(window).scroll(function() {

 if ($(this).scrollTop() > 100) {
 if (!inserted) {
 home.html(headerimage);
 inserted = true;
 }
 }
 else if (inserted) {
 $('.Header').html(headerimage);
 home.text('home');
 inserted = false;
 }
});
});
```

```css
body {
  height: 1500px;
}

a, div {
  position: fixed;
}

div {
  top: 50px;
}
```

```html
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<a href="#" class="thome">home</a>
<div class="Header">
  <img src="//www.anony.ws/i/2015/10/26/kitten.jpg">
</div>
```

Comment: No problem at all, there seems to be a little more to it - officially you cannot pass objects to `.html()`. But I'll post an update with additional info. Interesting question this turned out to be!

Comment: Thank for your help. any way to return orginal image while scrolling up?

Comment: Remove it again and place it back into the header you mean?

Comment: yes. place image back into header, also keep home link.

Comment: Okay, so reverse back to the original situation if I get it correctly... let me make a fiddle.

Comment: Glad to help and thanks for following up. Having learned something myself here is also worthwhile!

Comment: :D great. I checked as best answer :)